# Logo Keeps Knocking Links Over A Abit

Tags: html, css, image, navigation, src

I am trying to add a logo to my navigation but for some weird reason it keeps knocking the links to the side a little bit. I even tried float left and re-sizing the image so I am not to sure to why its doing this

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Spudster/ufWda/)

```
<style>
    #navigation {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: #ffffff;
        height: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 15px;
        /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
        /* Adds the transparent background */
        background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
        color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
    }
    #navigation a {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #navigation a:hover {
        color: grey;
    }
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    ul li {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #000
    }
    li ul {
        display: none;
    }
    ul li a {
        display: block;
        background: #000;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        color: #fff;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
        background: #f00;
    }
    li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }
    li:hover li {
        float: none;
    }
    li:hover a {
        background: #000000;
    }
    li:hover li a:hover {
        background: #000;
    }
    #drop-nav li ul li {
        border-top: 0px;
    }
    #main_logo {
        float: left;
    }
</style>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>Static Navigation</title>
</head>


<div id="navigation">
    HAD THE IMG SRC TAG HERE
    <text id="links">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="about.php">About</a>
        <a href="social.php">Social</a>

        <li style='display: inline-block;'><a href="#">Community</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/forums">Forums</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/news">News </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style='display: inline-block;'><a href="#">More</a>
            <ul>

                <li><a href="donate.php">Donate</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </text>
</div>
```

What else can I do to stop it from being moved I want it to stay right in the center.

Thanks!

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle.net

Comment: no problem give me one secound

Comment: if you look closely there not perfectly sitting in the centre
http://jsfiddle.net/Spudster/ufWda/ and thats the smallest logo :/

Comment: I've edited my fiddle based on your fiddle, should be perfect now check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this CSS and applying it to the image.

```
.image {
    left: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 8%;
}
```

you need `position: absolute;` and `left: 0%;` if you don't want the links to move at all

http://jsfiddle.net/EZx99/15/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ;) seems to still move a few pixels to the right compared to not having a logo but it helps a bit.now apllying an image 100px

Comment: edited fiddle to make text perfectly aligned in center

Comment: Thanks again! ;) give me 10 minutes and I will test it

Comment: Thanks works perfectly ;) I don't like asking questions but things do get technical sometimes